# Facebook API posting with PHP <5.5 without CurlFile class

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm having trouble uploading a file to facebook with PHP versions before 5.5 where CURLFile class is not available.

As I understand, I should use @filepath as the source and that should work, but for some reason it returns

```
Exception occured, code: 353 with message: (#353) You must select a video file to upload.
```

I've tried sending the path using realpath() function, that doesn't work.

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
                  $session, 'POST', '/me/videos', array(
                    'source' => '@'.realpath($url),                
                    'description' => $description,
                    'title' => $title
                  )
                ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I've also tried setting fileUpload to true in the parameters, that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `realpath($url)`? Is it actually a local file? (And if so, why is the variable named `$url` …?)

Comment: It is, yes, full path to the local file, I have also tried hardcoding it, I don't know what to tell you about the variable name, that's how it's named.

Comment: Can you try if uploading a photo as described in this example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto/4.0.0 works? If that works with the `'source' => '@/path/to/file.name'` syntax, but for videos it doesn’t, then this might be a bug.